# How to acknowledge someone when I use his function for my R package?

Tags: r, cran

I'm currently building my own R package where I need to use a C++ function written by someone else. According to the rules of CRAN submission, how should I acknowledge the original author? Should I add him as author or contributor or copyright holder in the Authors@R field of my package? And if so, should I also contact the original author for his approval? Thank you very much in advance for any help provided!

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no single answer,
and people have different opinions on what you should/must do,
or rather about how you should do it,
so I'll give you my take on it with an example.

I used code from [this repository](https://github.com/lemire/lbimproved),
which is under an Apache 2.0 license.
In your case, you'd have to check which license the original author used, if any.
The Apache license states that you should at least include some copyright notice,
so in my R package, inside the `inst` folder,
I added a file named `COPYRIGHTS` specifying:

> The code in
>
> - src/utils/envelope.cpp
>
> was adapted from third-party code to which the following applies:
>
> Copyright 2008 Daniel Lemire
>
> ...

That gets displayed [on CRAN under Copyright](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dtwclust).

I'm not sure what happens if the original author doesn't specify a license.
Some people consider that public domain if the code is freely available.

See also [CRAN policies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html),
and maybe [this reference too](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Alexis!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you read the documentation on the function and see if it contains an email address or other contact information.

As to attribution - generally authorship is the people who were actively involved in writing the package - you and anyone else working alongside you to write this package.

If you used someones work inside the package (and you are able to use it: check the user license and/or get permission) you can reference it properly (name of author, copyright information, date) in the documentation, and provide a link to the author's webpage/function webpage.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Bob!